# redirect user to error page (xhtml) after conversation expired through web.xml

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish, cdi, web.xml, weld

My environment is: NetBeans7.2.1, GlassFish3.1, JSF2 and Weld 1.1.0.

When the conversation time expires, I would like to redirect to error.xhtml page. 
Inside web.xml I added this code:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.jboss.weld.context.NonexistentConversationException</exception-type>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

But then I get this exception error:

```
WARNING: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve@365f4aa6: Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=org.jboss.weld.context.NonexistentConversationException, location=/error.xhtml]
javax.servlet.ServletException: WELD-000321 No conversation found to restore for id 1
```

When I use Servlet Listener named ErrorHandler to catch this exception with this code inside the web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.jboss.weld.context.NonexistentConversationException</exception-type>
    <location>/ErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

It works fine, and I'm redirecting to error.xhtml from there.

I need the location to work directly throgh the web.xml (and not thriugh the servlet).

I tried changing the `xhtml` page to `html` , it still did not work but the exception was diffrent:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces     Servlet threw exception
 org.jboss.weld.context.NonexistentConversationException: WELD-000321 No conversation found to restore for id 1
```

I also tried changing the root of the location to `/faces/error.xhtml` , and it still did not work.

What could be the problem? How can I redirect to a page from the web.xml ?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `nocid` parameter to the URL because the reason for your error is that CDI is sending non-existing conversation id to the `error.xhtml` page. So try following

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.jboss.weld.context.NonexistentConversationException</exception-type>
    <location>/error.xhtml?nocid=true</location>
</error-page>
```

More info [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/custom-error-pages-for-expired-conversations-involving-cdi-and-jsf.html?ModPagespeed=noscript)

Comment: this is the error: `WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
org.jboss.weld.context.NonexistentConversationException: WELD-000321 No conversation found to restore for id 1`

Comment: Wow, then I don' know, this is exactly what `nocid` param is supposed to prevent

Comment: even if `error.xhtml` does not use the conversation ? any idea what can cause this ? it's seems that it cannot find the page, i have no idea why.....