# Java ee session/conversation/view timeout redirection

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi, session-timeout, viewexpiredexception

My environment is: NetBeans7.2.1, GlassFish3.1, JSF2 and Weld 1.1.0.

I'm trying to redirect to an error page in one of these cases  ( session/conversation/view timeout ).

From what I read there are number of options:

1. Using `<error-page>` inside `web.xml` (but for some reason when I use `location` with `error.xhtml` page it's not working, only with a servlet - asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535037/redirect-user-to-error-page-xhtml-after-conversation-expired-through-web-xml) question about this issue).
2. Using `<exception-handler-factory>` inside `faces-config.xml` which will use a `CustomExceptionHandler` like in [this](http://wmarkito.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/adding-global-exception-handling-using-jsf-2-x-exceptionhandler/) example.
3. Using a `@WebFilter` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969) example.

My main problem is that after I'm redirecting to `error.xhtml` page I want to disable going back to previous pages. so even if the user clickes on the back button he will still be redirected to the error page.

I was able to redirect to an error page when an exception accourd , but was not able to clear the cache so when the user goes back he still can see the previous page content.

I don't fully understand what are the diffrances between the 3 options above, and exactly what is the role of each option.

Can someone please explain ?

what is the diffrence between

`NavigationHandler nav = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler(); 
nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "/error");
facesContext.renderResponse();`

and

`((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("yourCustomJSF.jsf");` ?

How can I handle these exceptions by redirecting and clearing the cache so that the user will not be able to see previous page ?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for handle expired session/view:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/index.jsf</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

> My main problem is that after I'm redirecting to error.xhtml page I want to disable going back to previous pages. so even if the user clickes on the back button he will still be redirected to the error page

to do this use a filter to not  cache the page and send the request to the server instead
see this to get the code of filter

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034603/2422368